# Python variable checking

Tags: python-3.x

How would I get Python to check a variable to see if it is an integer and below a specific number then carry on depending on the result perhaps breaking from a loop.
so something roughly like this:

```
x = input

if x is integer AND below 10:

    print ("X is a number below 10")
    break from loop

elif x is NOT an integer:

    print ("X is not an integer try again")
    ask again
Else: 

    print ("Error")
    ask again
```

Comment: Read some about basic python's syntax. Consider writing a loop, when you want to break from it.

Comment: We could trivially write this for you, but it would be better for you to read about comparison and try using the 'break' and 'continue' statements yourself.

Answer (score 1):

pretty sure this works :D thanks

while True:

```
x = input("Enter Something: ")  #user input

 if x.isdigit() == True:
     if (int(x)>=1) and (int(x)<=2): #if it is 1 or 2
         print (x)
         break
     elif (int(x)>2): #or if its above 2
         print ("To Large")
     else:
         print ("Else") 

 elif x.isdigit() == False: #data non integer
     print ("please try again")
 else:
     print ("ERROR") #error with input
```

print ("Hello") #show the loop broke correctly